# find a tag by beautifulsoup and extract element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In a HTML file, I have a tag that **includes** `<source type="audio/mpeg" src="/us/media` in that, and extract `src` element from that using bs4?

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the desired output:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148'}


res = requests.get('https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/vulnerable', headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
srcs = soup.select('source[src*="us/media"]')
for src in srcs:
    try:
        print(src['src'])
    except:
        pass
```

Output:

```
/us/media/english/us_pron/v/vul/vulne/vulnerable.mp3
/us/media/english/us_pron_ogg/v/vul/vulne/vulnerable.ogg
/us/media/english/uk_pron/u/ukv/ukvor/ukvorte027.mp3    
/us/media/english/uk_pron_ogg/u/ukv/ukvor/ukvorte027.ogg
/us/media/english/us_pron/v/vul/vulne/vulnerable.mp3    
/us/media/english/us_pron_ogg/v/vul/vulne/vulnerable.ogg
/us/media/english/us_pron/e/eus/eus74/eus74904.mp3
/us/media/english/us_pron_ogg/e/eus/eus74/eus74904.ogg
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm not similar to bs4, can you give me the complete code?

Comment: Can you share the url along with a little bit  details?

Comment: <https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/vulnerable>

Comment: @PaliProx, I've updated